# How to export table from Netbeans, Java DB (Derby) Database

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

I need to export the structure of some tables so I can easily recreate them on a different database. I tried to use the Grab Structure but this seems to work only if I try to create a new table within Netbeans. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I have, not was I was looking for. Thanks for the reply anyway and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3):

**Export a table structure**

In Netbeans

right click a table to export -> `Grab Structure`

[image]

Save the file

[image]

- right click a table to recreate -> `Recreate Table`
- open the file just created
- choose `Edit table script`

[image]

- do a Ctrl-a and Ctrl-c . To mark all and copy to clipboard.
- close with `cancel`.

[image]

#### Important close Netbeans to close all connections ( a disconnect inside Netbeans is not enough)

Go to your Databases folder

[image]

inside this folder call your `ij`
otherwise the database **can not be found.**

[image]

`connect` and `select` look if the right database is opened.

- connect 'jdbc:derby:sample;user=app;password=app';
- select * from FRIENDS;

[image]

- open Notepad and paste the structure from the clipboard.
- for later use save it to file.
- here I renamed `FRIENDS` to `MYFRIENDS` to not overwright my `Friends` table.
- Select all and copy again.
- paste to `ij` and hit `enter`
- do a select to test if table `MYFRIENDS` is created.

[image]

Now we close `ij` with `quit;` to test in Netbeans we open Netbeans again.
And here it is. everything in the right position with the right properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apache DDLUtils: http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/ . It can export and import schema from many database implementations (this text added to exceed the minimum answer limit).