# How can I export created derby database from Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I creacted a new database with some tables and datas in derby, Netbeans.

How can I export this database and how can I insert it in a new computer to Netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

It's so wide question, and you can find on the official tutorial the same answer. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

Comment: I cant find it. Not writes about how to export the whole database.

Comment: Here is a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250004/how-to-export-table-from-netbeans-java-db-derby-database. I am just looking for more

Comment: Its export only a table, not the full database. I would like to export all datas in one step and import it an other computer.